# Euler and Bernoulli Polynomial Identity Proof

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request

Given that the Euler Polynomials $E_n(z)$ are defined in terms of the generating function

$$\frac{2e^{xz}}{e^x+1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty E_n(z)\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

and that the Bernoulli Polynomials $B_n(z)$ are defined in terms of a similar generating function

$$\frac{xe^{xz}}{e^x-1}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty B_n(z)\frac{x^n}{n!}$$

I am trying to find proofs on line of the following identity between the two polynomials:

$$E_{n-1}(z)=\frac{2^n}{n}\left[B_n\left(\frac{z+1}{2}\right)-B_n\left(\frac{z}{2}\right)\right]$$

I am looking for multiple proofs if possible but am having trouble locating the specific proofs.  Are there any individuals that can help me find this particular proof(s)?

Comment: This is a special case of Raabes multiplication formula (http://dlmf.nist.gov/24.4#v) for $m=2, x \rightarrow x/2.$ For a proof see Sun's paper
http://math.nju.edu.cn/~zwsun/BerE.pdf (bottom of page 8). (**Disclaimer**: I am not a specialist!)

Comment: You mean $x\mapsto z$...I'll change it... Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here we use for convenience only the following notation for the generating functions of *[Bernoulli polynomials and Euler polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Generating_functions)*

\begin{align*}
  \sum_{n=0}^\infty E_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}&=\frac{2e^{xt}}{e^t+1}\\
  \sum_{n=0}^{\infty}B_n(x)\frac{t^n}{n!}&=\frac{te^{xt}}{e^t-1}
  \end{align*}

> We show the following is valid
>   \begin{align*}
>   E_{n-1}(x)=\frac{2^n}{n}\left[B_n\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)-B_n\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]\qquad\qquad n\geq 1\tag{1}
>   \end{align*}

$$ $$

> We multiply both sides of (1) with $\frac{n}{2^n}$ and consider the generating function for the LHS
>
> \begin{align*}
> \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}&E_{n-1}(x)\frac{n}{2^n}\frac{t^n}{n!}\\
> &=\frac{t}{2}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}E_{n-1}(x)\frac{t^{n-1}}{2^{n-1}(n-1)!}\tag{2}\\
> &=\frac{t}{2}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}E_{n}(x)\frac{t^{n}}{2^{n}n!}\tag{3}\\
> &=\frac{t}{2}\frac{2e^{\frac{1}{2}xt}}{e^{\frac{1}{2}t}+1}\\
> &=\frac{te^{\frac{1}{2}xt}}{e^{\frac{1}{2}t}+1}\\
>   \end{align*}
>
> We obtain as generating function for the RHS of (1)
>
> \begin{align*}
>   \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}&\left[B_n\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)-B_n\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\right]\frac{t^n}{n!}\\
>   &=  \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)\frac{t^n}{n!}
>   -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}B_n\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)\frac{t^n}{n!}\\
> &=\frac{te^{\frac{1}{2}(x+1)t}}{e^t-1}-\frac{te^{\frac{1}{2}xt}}{e^t-1}\tag{4}\\
>   &=\frac{te^{\frac{1}{2}xt}}{e^t-1}\left(e^{\frac{t}{2}}-1\right)\\
>   &=\frac{te^{\frac{1}{2}xt}}{e^{\frac{1}{2}t}+1}\tag{5}
>   \end{align*}
>
> and the claim follows.

*Comment:*

- In (2) we simplify and rearrange the sum
- In (3) we shift the index by one and observe that we get the generating function of Euler polynomials with argument $\frac{t}{2}$.
- In (4) we use the generating functions for the Bernoulli polynomials with arguments $\frac{x+1}{2}$ and $\frac{x}{2}$. We also use implicitly $B_0\left(\frac{x+1}{2}\right)=B_0\left(\frac{x}{2}\right)=1$.
- In (5) we use $e^t-1=\left(e^\frac{t}{2}+1\right)\left(e^\frac{t}{2}-1\right)$

> **Addendum:**  According to OPs comment some links with related info
>
> - In *[Eulerian Numbers and Polynomials](http://www.jstor.org/stable/3029225?seq=1#page_scan_tab_contents)* by L. Carlitz we find near formula (5.4) the following generalisation for $m$ even
>     \begin{align*}
>   m^n\sum_{s=0}^{m-1}(-1)^sB_n\left(x+\frac{s}{m}\right)=-\frac{n}{2}E_{n-1}(mx)
>   \end{align*}
> - In *[Generating functions for generalized Stirling type numbers, Array type polynomials, Eulerian type polynomials and their applications](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1186%5C%2F1687-1812-2013-87)* by Yilmaz Simsek the same formula in (29) is provided.
> - In *[Binomial Identities (vol.8)](http://www.math.wvu.edu/~gould/Vol.8.PDF)* by H.W. Gould we find the formula given as (3.3).
> - In *[The Umbral Calculus](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0125943806)* by S. Roman the formula is stated besides many other related formulas in section 2.5 Appell sequences.

*Hint:* Besides these references I suppose practically each section in Wiki's *[Bernoulli polynomials and Euler polynomials](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bernoulli_polynomials#Generating_functions)* could be used as starting point for a proof of the stated formula.

Comment: Are there any other proofs in the literature around as well?  Not that I dislike it, but i have a problem and want to compare multiple approaches to it.  Thank you for answering.

Comment: @Eleven-Eleven: I've added some hints in my answer.